# Lower bounding a exponential/binomial expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

I have been struggling to lower bound the following expression

\begin{equation}
f(N):= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2^N} \sum_{k=1}^{i} 2^{i-k} \binom{N+k-2}{k-1} ,
\end{equation}

with some simple formula, without the need of exactly calculating it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

- More precisely, one can go through it to re-write it as

\begin{align}
f(N)=&\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2^N} \sum_{k=1}^{i} 2^{i-k} \binom{N+k-2}{k-1} =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^{i}\frac{2^{i-k-N}}{(k-1)!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-2}(N+k-2-j)\\ &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^{i}\frac{2^{i-k-N}}{(k-1)!}N^{k-1}+\frac{2^{-k-N}}{(k-1)!}N^{k-1}N^{k-2}+...  \\ &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{2^{1-i-N}}{(i-1)!}N^{i-1}+\frac{2^{-i-N}}{(i-3)!}\left(1+\frac{4}{(i-2)} \right)N^{i-2} + ... \\ &= \frac{2^{1-2N}}{(N-1)!}N^{N-2}+\frac{2^{2N}}{(N-3)!}\left(1+\frac{8}{(N-2)} \right)N^{N-3} + ...
\end{align}

My goal is to lower bound these expressions with some straightforward expressions without precisely calculating them. Any idea will be more than welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Compute the values for $N=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ which are $1/2,5/8,11/12,93/64,193/80,793/192,1619/224$. The numerators seem to be [OEIS A120778](https://oeis.org/A120778), the denominators I don't know. Try to figure it out. Good luck!